# how to continue from the activity that I quit?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm Creating A game so I have several Sharedpreference for the score and 2 for check if I was on this activity to not repeat it. So when i quit the app(restart) and reopen it I Want when  pressing  the start button and it continues from A2 or A3 or ... only if i exited from this activities but my sharedPreference not allowing it Because it's job is to not repeat the activity if the user enter it once. This is my 2 sharedpreference please someone guide me what to do...

```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("a", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (pref.getBoolean("aa", false)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, A2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {


        SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("a", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref1.edit();
        edt.putBoolean("aa", true);
        edt.commit();

    }
```

**I just want when i exit the app or pause it to continue from where the user Stops**
 ** i don't want to repeat the same activity if the user already answered the question but if he exits without answering I want to continue from where he left** 
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Put a `return` after your `finish` statement in the IF loop. Please remember `finish` does not alter the control flow but it merely asks the system to finish your activity. So if you don't want rest of your code to execute, put in a return statement. I guess rest of your code is fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it didn't worked
maybe I wasn't clear enough it is a game starts from A1 then A2 then A3 when the user answers all this and quit the app and reopen it and pressed start button it will continue from A4 but the problem is when he exits let say form A3 without answering it and reopen the app it continue from A4 not A3 because of this SharedPreference

Comment: In that case, you should save to the preference only when the user has performed the necessary action in your activity. Let's say, if you wanted the user to answer something in A3, then save to the preference only when he does the same. In any case, if this too does not answer your question, i guess you need to explain the question more clearly

Comment: i don't want to repeat the same activity if the user already answered the question but if he exits without answering I want to continue from where he left

Comment: And you want to do this by maintaining the state in the preference right ? then edit the shared preference when user has answered the question in an activity. Right now you are doing the edit in `onCreate` which will be executed irrespective of whether the user has answered the question or not.

Comment: actually i don't know how to edit on this sharedPreference because it will be like the opposite of this one :O

Comment: What do you mean by 'on this sharedpreference' and 'opposite of this one'

Comment: the first  sharedpreference in my code  checks if the user was on this activity before if yes intents to the next activity 
so how i will create i new sharedpreference in onCreate does check if he answered or not 
1-will check if the user was on this activity then intent(it doesn't matter if he answered)
2-will check if the answer was answered to intent or re-intent send activity
i want step 2